# verilog code for a state machine

Tags: verilog

I'm given a combinational circuit and I will design a verilog code for that circuit. It's about state machines. The equations are:

```
A(t+1)=A(t)+B(t);
B(t+1)=A(t)'+B(t);
```

There is no  other outputs or inputs. I have tried few codes and they didn't work. I'm confused about assignig A,B,A_next,B_next as inputs,outputs and wires. Can anyone give me a little clue so that I can try it again?

```
module statemac_posed(clk,a,b);
input clk;
output a,b;
reg a_next,b_next;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
a=a_next;
b=b_next;
a_next=a|b;
b_next=~a|b;

end

endmodule
```

Comment: The circuit has 3 inputs (Ain, Bin, clock), 2 states (Ast, Bst) and 2 outputs (Aout, Bout), right? What does `A(t)'` mean ( `'` )?

Comment: I have put it to mean " not", ~A(t).

Comment: I should add that A_next is the input for the first DFF and so is B_next for the second DFF.

Comment: Then probably just declare 2 registers `Ast` and `Bst` in the module, make `alwais` block sensitive to clock and assign expressions to these registers, and assign these registers to outputs. If this dosn't work - please provide Your non-working code.

Comment: Should I assign expressions to registers and registers to outputs in the same begin-end block?

Comment: I think yes. I see no reason, why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Can you please check my question again. I have added the code.The errors are    ERROR:HDLCompilers:44 - "statemac_posed.v" line 28 Illegal left hand side of blocking assignment
ERROR:HDLCompilers:247 - "statemac_posed.v" line 29 Reference to scalar wire 'b' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue
ERROR:HDLCompilers:44 - "statemac_posed.v" line 29 Illegal left hand side of blocking assignment

Comment: I think You need `<=` instead of `=`.

Comment: It didn't change anything  when I tried on my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from a flip-flop is your next value, as synchronous logic you could just write:

For FPGA `intial` can be used to set initial values for ASIC active low resets are used

```
module statemac_posed(
  input      clk,
  output reg a,
  output reg b
);

initial begin
  a = 'b0;
  b = 'b0;
end

//On clock edge update a &b with new values based on previous a & b value
always@(posedge clk) begin
  a <= a|b;  
  b <= ~a|b;
end

endmodule
```

This is equivalent to :

```
module statemac_posed(
  input      clk,
  output reg a,
  output reg b
);
  reg a_next;
  reg b_next;

//Combinatorial take outputs from flip-flops and combinatorial define next value
always @* begin
  a_next = a|b; 
  b_next = ~a|b;
end   

initial begin
  a = 'b0;
  b = 'b0;
end

//on Clock edge take the next values
always @(posedge clk) begin
  a <= a_next;
  b <= b_next;
end

endmodule
```

Any variable assigned to inside an `initial` or `always` needs to be of type `reg`. `logic` is also valid if using SystemVerilog. Not doing this was the cause of the errors you mentioned in comments.

This should give some insight into how to use verilog.
NB: use blocking (`=`) with combinatorial (`@*`). non-blocking (`<=`) with edge triggered (`@(posedge clk)`) to correctly describe hardware.